# Существуют ли какие-то затраты на преобразование объектов?

Tags: c#, .net, преобразование-типов

С преобразованием значимого типа в объект и обратно все понятно — там появляются доп. операции на упаковку/распаковку.

А есть ли какие-то затраты при преобразовании объектов между дочерним типом и базовым типом?

Comment: Неявное преобразование: класс в любой его базовый класс или интерфейс, - ничего не стоит. А вот любое явное преобразование уже чего-то да стоит: преобразование через as правда чуть быстрее, поскольку не проверяет типы и не выбрасывает исключения в случае неудачи.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Неявные преобразования

Неявные преобразования проверяются компилятором и после компиляции уже не существуют, соответственно, дополнительных затрат не требуют.

Это можно проверить, прочитав IL-код после компиляции:

Код на C#:

```
class A{}
class B : A{}
...
B b = new B();
A a = new A();
A target; 
target = b;
Console.WriteLine(target);
target = a;
Console.WriteLine(target);
```

Сгенерерированный IL:

```
IL_0001:  newobj     instance void B::.ctor()                             //new B()
IL_0006:  stloc.0                                                         //b = 
IL_0007:  newobj     instance void A::.ctor()                             //new A()
IL_000c:  stloc.1                                                         //a = 
IL_000d:  ldloc.0
IL_000e:  stloc.2
IL_000f:  ldloc.2
IL_0010:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
IL_0015:  nop
IL_0016:  ldloc.1
IL_0017:  stloc.2
IL_0018:  ldloc.2
IL_0019:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
```

Как видно, в обоих случаях генерируется пара инструкций `ldloc` (загрузка переменной в стек) и `stloc` (выгрузка из стека в переменную). Никаких дополнительных телодвижений при преобразовании типа не выполняется.

Аналогично, если Вы вызываете метод вида: `A a = someClass.generateA()`, то среда выполнения не проверяет *реальный* тип объекта, который вернулся из A, ожидая, что компилятор уже выполнил проверку соответствия типов.

### Явные преобразования

Явные преобразования генерируют дополнительные инструкции, которые требуют определенных затрат. Приведение типа — инструкцию `castclass`, преобразования через `as` и `is` — `isinst`. Обе эти инструкции описаны в [спецификации CLI](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Соответственно, код на C#:

```
A a = new B();
Console.WriteLine((B) a);
Console.WriteLine(a as B);
Console.WriteLine(a is B);
```

будет преобразован в следующий IL:

```
IL_0001:  newobj     instance void B::.ctor()
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ldloc.0
IL_0008:  castclass  B
IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
IL_0012:  nop
IL_0013:  ldloc.0
IL_0014:  isinst     B
IL_0019:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
IL_001e:  nop
IL_001f:  ldloc.0
IL_0020:  isinst     B
IL_0025:  ldnull
IL_0026:  cgt.un
IL_0028:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
```

Если типы не сходятся, то `castclass` сгенерирует исключение, что несколько более затратно. Соответственно, если вероятность этого высока, то лучше применять `as` чем `cast`. В случае когда типы сходятся ощутимой разницы быть не должно.

Обе инструкции применяются очень часто, работают быстро и крайне оптимизированы. Навряд ли приведение типа будет узким местом в Вашем коде, поэтому в большинстве случаев важно писать то приведение, которое имеет больше смысла и лучше читается.

Достаточно обширное обсуждение разницы `as vs cast` на английском Stack Overflow: [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496096)

Comment: Забавно, но в примере из секции "Явные преобразования" JIT знает, что в a лежит B, и вообще выбрасывает проверки на тип, оставляя только вызовы Console.WriteLine. Если a передать параметром, а не инициализировать прямо в методе - проверки остаются.

Comment: @PashaPash Действительно забавно, хоть от оптимизатора и можно ожидать чего-то подобного.